# Separate nested dict inside a series column of a dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

[image: dataframe]

Trying to extract the username from the author column of the dataframe for each row, the author column is series & the individual values inside author is a dictionary.

Converting the author column directly to df & & changing the type of author column not helping to reach the goal.

I'm only able to reference the username via

```
df_item['author'][0]['username']
```

Trying to get a separate username column

```
id                  type   content        channel_id           username
1047404831062638613 0      It’s really..   1047331843898359849  lips
1047333443165499432 0      okay,thankyou   1047331843898359849   Mj
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how you are initially reading the data into a df also as there are likely opportunities to fix this at that stage. See, e.g., [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). But in general, post a minimal example with sample data we can copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
df['author_username'] = df['author'].apply(lambda x: x['username'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the series to list then pass it to pandas dataframe and it takes care of the rest.

```
df_new = DataFrame(list(df2["author"]))
```